# Redirecting folder to another folder avoiding other .htaccess rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have the root folder of my website with an existing website. I have developed a codeigniter based admin system which I wish to post in the /editor folder, however all mod_rewriting I have done seems to be in vain as, if anything rewrites, it cant access the input string or the index.php file appears. Here is the structure:

```
/
    /editor
        index.php
        .htaccess
    index.php
    .htaccess
```

Here is my current .htaccess file at the root of the site:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule  %{REQUEST_URI}^/?editor/(.*)$ (.*)/editor/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond $1 ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?p=homepage [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|editor|css|pdf|eshot|js|fonts|images)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?p=$1 [L]
```

**Edit**

This current rule displays the root index.php file when you navigate to the /editor sub folder, whereas it should show the index.php file from the /editor folder.

**Re-edit**

It might be the .htaccess file in the /editor sub folder, here is the code from that:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|lib|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's look at it step by step.

First let's scrap this rule, which is ungrammatical because it uses regex on the right side:

```
RewriteRule  %{REQUEST_URI}^/?editor/(.*)$ (.*)/editor/$1 [R,L]
```

The second rule can be abridged to this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ ?p=homepage [L]
```

The third rule can be rewritten like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:index\.php|editor|css|pdf|eshot|js|fonts|images))([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Summarizing, it looks to me like you could abridge your rules like so:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ ?p=homepage [L]
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:index\.php|editor|css|pdf|eshot|js|fonts|images))([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi there, I think I may have explained this slightly obscurely, please see my edit for clarification :)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Maybe it is the .htaccess file in the other folder? I'll post that in my question.

Comment: I was also missing a ? in the second htaccess file, which menat your last edit worked :)